# Why does adding keyword make my query not work?

Tags: elasticsearch

Im making a query that can filter out content based on certain fields and I had this.

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 10,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "filter" : [
        {
          "bool" : {
            "must_not" : [
              {
                "terms" : {
                  "metadata.subtype" : [
                    "Type1"
                  ],
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            ],
          }
        }
      ],
    }
  },
}
```

With a object like this

```
{
  id: "SomeId" <- Text
    metadata: {
      subtype: "Type1" <- Keyword
    }
}
```

And that works fine for that one field, but if instead of `metadata.subtype` I used `id` it no longer works unless I make it `id.keyword`.

But then `metadata.subtype.keyword` does not work and I dont understand why. Can you not use `.keyword` with fields that are indexed as keywords?

Comment: can you please share your complete index mapping, and some sample index data ?

Comment: @ESCoder the example object I provided is some sample data, I also annotated it with the type of each field. Let me know if you need something more specific!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`terms` query works with fields of `keyword` type, so it won't match your `id` field if it is `text`.

If you really want to filter against text field, use another query, e.g. `match`. But if you want to actually use `terms` query, you need to change the type of `id` field to keyword.

Another common approach is to define a field of `text` type, but add a `keyword` subfield so that it can also be matched by `term` and `terms` queries.

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/multi-fields.html

Here's an example index mapping that would probably match your needs.

```
{
  "mapping": {
    "properties": {
      "id": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "raw": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "metadata.subtype": {
        "type": "keyword"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can filter with any of the following queries:

- `{ "match": { "id": "text" } }`
- `{ "terms": { "id.raw": "text" } }`
- `{ "terms": { "metadata.subtype": "value" } }`